# Python Pandas Dataframe with .map()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've defined

```
iphone_dict = {
  "iPhone 14 Pro Max": 4323,
  "iPhone 14 Plus": 4325,
  "iPhone 14 Pro": 3200,
  "iPhone 14": 3279,
  "iPhone 13 Pro Max": 3095,
  "iPhone 13 Pro": 3095,
  "iPhone 13": 3095,
  "iPhone 13 mini": 2406,
  "iPhone 12 Pro Max": 2815,
  "iPhone 12 Pro": 2815,
  "iPhone 12": 2815,
  "iPhone 12 mini": 2406,
  "iPhone SE (2022)": 2018,
  "iPhone SE (2020)": 1821,
  "iPhone 11 Pro Max": 3969,
  "iPhone 11 Pro": 3046,
  "iPhone 11": 3110,
  "iPhone XS Max": 3174,
  "iPhone XS": 2658,
  "iPhone XR": 2716,
  "iPhone X": 2716,
  "iPhone 8 Plus": 2691
}
```

I want to replace the "battery" column if the "clearedPhoneName" contains 'iPhone' matching above iphone_dict.

Here is my code to do that.

```
dfClean2['Battery'] = dfClean2[dfClean2['CleanedPhoneName'].str.contains('iPhone', case=False)].map(iphone_dict)
```

When I run the code, it's coming up with: 'DataFrame' object has not attribut 'map'.

Any advice would be appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what does ```dfClean2[dfClean2['CleanedPhoneName'].str.contains('iPhone', case=False)]['Battery'].map(iphone_dict)``` do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np    
dfClean2['Battery'] = np.where(dfClean2['CleanedPhoneName'].isin(iphone_dict.keys()), 
    dfClean2['CleanedPhoneName'].map(iphone_dict), dfClean2['Battery'])
```